# Cannot connect postgreSQL with sequelize in docker

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I've written the code to connect to the database first and then start the app server. But looks like the database connection is not working when I try to run `docker-compose up` command. I'm getting the following error in the docker logs

```
{"level":"error","message":"Unable to connect to the database: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db","name":"SequelizeConnectionError","original":{"code":"EAI_AGAIN","errno":-3001,"hostname":"db","syscall":"getaddrinfo"},"parent":{"code":"EAI_AGAIN","errno":-3001,"hostname":"db","syscall":"getaddrinfo"},"stack":"SequelizeConnectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db\n    at Client._connectionCallback (/src/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:143:24)\n    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/src/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:318:19)\n    at Client._handleErrorEvent (/src/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:328:19)\n    at Connection.emit (events.js:400:28)\n    at Socket.reportStreamError (/src/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:57:12)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)\n    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)"}
```

The following is my start.ts file where the sequelize connection is been written

```
//sequelize is been imported from the database file.
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    logger.info('Connected to the database.');
    app.listen(port, () => {
      logger.info(`Server is running on port ${port}.`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

This is my database file where I'm mentioning all the required information about the DB

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME!, process.env.DB_USER!, process.env.DB_PASSWORD!, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST!,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,
});

export default sequelize;
```

The following is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  userDB:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: userDb
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Sample .env file for the reference

```
PORT=3000
DB_HOST=db
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_NAME=userDb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used 'userDB' as database host name in docker-compose.yml, and 'db' in .env file. You need to choose something one.

Comment: I have declared ${DB_HOST} in the yml file so that takes the value from env. So both are the same here right ? also you specified 'userDB' which is the database name.

Comment: The `DB_HOST` needs to match the Compose service name of the database.  The `DB_NAME` is the name of the database once you've connected to it.